# WCF pub-sub model, Invoking Subscribers all at once

Tags: c#, wcf, publish-subscribe

We have a WCF publish-subscribe model application, It works fine.

But this part of the code.

```
  foreach (SubList subscriber in subscribers.ToList())
        {
           try
             {
               object ClientResult;
               ClientResult = publishMethodInfo.Invoke(subscriber.CallBackId, new object[] { ClData });
                }
          }
```

Is there any way I invoke all subscribers all at once. As the above code is in a loop fetching each subscriber and publishing. This is causing other subscribers to wait until prior is executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not invoke them in parallel?

```
Parallel.ForEach(subscribers.ToArray(), subscriber =>
{
    try
    {
        object ClientResult;
        ClientResult = publishMethodInfo.Invoke(
            subscriber.CallBackId, new object[] { ClData });
    }
    ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you steven...Sorry am new to parallel programming infact have never used it. I have a list of 500 subscribers with Parallel.forach is it ensured 500 clients were invoked? Inshort does 500 threads spawned simultaneously or else do I need to fine tune any ..Kindly suggest.

Comment: There will sertainly not be 500 threads. The TPL will devide the list over the available (work stealing) queues. The number of queues depends on your machine, but you can tune it. There are [overloads of the Parallel.ForEach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) method that allow you to specify the max degree of parallelism, among other options.